# Does a digital signature ensure the entire message is encrypted?

Tags: security, encryption, digital-signature, signature

Does a digital signature ensure that the entire message is encrypted?

Comment: Short answer: **no**. A digital signature is something total different compared to an encryption (although the same kind of keys are used, e.g. RSA keys). The signature just says "the following data are signed with a specific private key". You can verify the signature with the corresponding public key. The kind of data (plaintext, binary data, encrypted data are out of scope for the signature.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not about programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. First of all, generally the message is first hashed using a cryptographically secure hash algorithm *as part of* the signature generation. The message itself is not converted to anything at all.

Even if the message is processed with the private key, anybody with the public key would be able to reverse the operation to get the value that is signed. And sometimes the verification just takes the hash as input and returns the result - as in `true` or `false` or an error or not.

As such, signature generation will never provide message confidentiality and therefore should not be considered encryption.